# Print preceding 0 when printing hex values in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I'm looking at `unsigned char` (byte) arrays in `gdb`, i.e.

```
(gdb) p/x buf@4
$76 = {0xac, 0xa, 0xb0, 0xa}
```

Is there a way of forcing the preceding 0s? i.e output like:

```
$76 = {0xac, 0x0a, 0xb0, 0x0a}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the gdb [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html#Output-Formats):

> `'z'`
>
> Like 'x' formatting, the value is treated as an integer and printed as hexadecimal, but leading zeros are printed to pad the value to the size of the integer type.

So...

```
(gdb) p/z buf@4
```